# Is filterFunction permanent?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Once you apply a filterFunction to an ArrayCollection, it's permanent, isn't it?

For example, I apply a filterFunction to a collection and make a remote call to repopulate the ArrayCollection via addItem().

Let's say 20 items were added.

If I then trace out the collection length it appears as 0. That's because the filter is in place and all the data I just added didn't meet the criteria.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once you apply a filterFunction to an ArrayCollection, it's permanent, isn't it?

Yes, until you change it.  Once you change it to something else and call `collection.refresh()`.

Comment: To remove active filter. ArrayCollection.filterFunc = null; ArrayCollection.refresh()